# In DirectX 8, how can I have a texture cover another texture only partially?

Tags: graphics, programming

I am creating a Real Time Strategy game with DirectX 8. However, DirectX 8 supports pixel shaders only minimally. Is there a way that I can change the colors of individual triangles before the mesh is drawn? I am using the "mesh" model type, so I might have to create my own model loader.

This is the code I currently have:

```
VOID Render()
{
    // Clear the backbuffer and the zbuffer
    g_pd3dDevice->Clear( 0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET|D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, 
                         D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0,0,255), 1.0f, 0 );
    
    // Begin the scene
    g_pd3dDevice->BeginScene();

    // Setup the world, view, and projection matrices
    SetupMatrices();

    // Meshes are divided into subsets, one for each material. Render them in
    // a loop
    for( DWORD i=0; i<g_dwNumMaterials; i++ )
    {
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTexture(1, g_pTexture);
        // Set the material and texture for this subset

        g_pd3dDevice->SetMaterial( &g_pMeshMaterials[i] );
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTexture( 0, g_pMeshTextures[i] );
        


        g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_ADDSIGNED);
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG2, D3DTA_DIFFUSE);
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_SELECTARG1);
        
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_ADDSIGNED);
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_COLORARG2, D3DTA_CURRENT);
        g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_DISABLE);
        
        //g_pd3dDevice->SetTextureStageState(1, D3DTADDRESS_MIRROR, 0x000000);
        
        // Draw the mesh subset
        g_pMesh->DrawSubset( i );
    }

    // End the scene
    g_pd3dDevice->EndScene();
    
    // Present the backbuffer contents to the display
    g_pd3dDevice->Present( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );
}
```

So currently, I am just adding a second texture to the texture that is originally with the model I am loading. however, the colors and everything else from the second texture are pasted completely over the first texture. The part I can’t figure out is how to make the second texture only cover parts of the first texture. I read something in Game Programming Gems about this, but it only discusses the idea for drawing individual triangles, not DirectX meshes.

Comment: DirectX 8 was current from c2001-2002.  It makes me feel old if the 21st century counts as Retrocomputing.

Comment: @Chenmunka I have bad news for you…

Comment: @Chenmunka haha DirectX 8 was released in 2001, 2 years before I was even alive. Anything after my time is what I consider not retro haha! Besides, gamedev.net just complains about everything, so here I am haha!

Comment: @Chenmunka That's because you **are** old.

Answer (score 1):

Given that Arg1 is the output of texture stage one, and Arg2 is the output of texture stage two, `D3DTOP_ADDSIGNED` appears to compute `Arg1 + Arg2 - 0.5`, which doesn't provide any mechanism to discard the output of either stage.

If you want one texture to replace the other only partially, `D3DTOP_BLENDTEXTUREALPHA` looks like a suitable `D3DTSS_COLOROP`; by computing `Arg1 * (alpha) + Arg2 * (1 - Alpha)` you can use the alpha channel of your second texture to determine where to replace the original colour and where to allow the original to show through.